Using the same deployment with different resources dependening on the node pool/taint
I have a cluster with two type of nodes: x86 and arm. The arm cores are a bit weaker, so I want to give pods on the arm nodes X1.5 the amount of cpu I give on the x86 nodes.
I could create two deployments but that complicates my Keda auto-scaler. Assuming I scale based on a queue, I could not find a way to set the ScaledObject on two deployments together.
Is there a way to give a container different resource limits depending on a node taint/affinity?

In Kubernetes you can manage resource allocation for pods based on the node characteristics using a combination of node affinity and resource requests limits. However since we cant directly set different resource limits for containers based on node type we can try doing it by the following method.
Node affinity: You can use the node affinity to control where your pods are scheduled.For example you can label your nodes  (eg., arch=x86 and arch=arm) and then set affinity rules in your pod specifications.
Refer to the below example:
affinity:
  nodeAffinity:

requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoreDuring
Execution: 
    nodeSelectorTerms:
       -matchExpressions:
         - key:arch
          operator:In
          Values:
             -arm

If you must have deployments for KEDA you can use KEDA’s scaled object to target the multiple deployments.

Yes, I know how to limit a pod to a specific node pool. The piece that I'm missing is how to scale them as one deployment. You say it can be done with KEDA but I failed to find how, do you have a more specific documentation about it?

KEDA does not support scaling multiple deployments as a single entity through Scaled Object but to achieve the similar thing you need to create an individual scaledObject for each deployment while using the same metrics.

Ensure both ScaledObjects use the same trigger config that points to the same external metric and try to tune the scaling parameters in both ScaleObject to maintain a balanced scaling strategy across both deployments.

You can refer to this Auto Scaling Microservices with Kubernetes Event-Driven Autoscaler (KEDA) blog written by Suman Das and check this KEDA FAQs to get more information.

Did you have time to check my comment? It helped you to solve your issue? If not ,I am happy to assist further.

No, my current solution is basically what you propose but it complicates the system. I can't have proper scaling with KEDA on multiple deployments. Sure I can play around with the parameters so it would work alright but it creates extra complexity that is unwarranted.

I am glad that you are going to tune the scaling parameters as suggested however if you find it is a extra complex you can adjust the thresholds for each deployment for the different capacities of node types.What should I do when someone answers my question?

Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further. What should I do when someone answers my question?

Hi, I'm still not sure what you mean by adjusting the thresholds. Currently my scaling parameters work but don't make sense since I had to take into account I have another scaled object on the same queue. I'm looking for a solution of a single deployment or a single scaled object.
